# Subgraphs of a bipartite graph $H$ as the intersection of two copies of $H$ in $K_{n,n}$.

Tags: graph-theory

Let $H$ be a bipartite graph. Is it necessarily the case that every subgraph of $H$ can appear as the intersection of two copies of $H$ in $K_{n,n}$ for large enough $n$? (Here $K_{n,n}$ is the complete bipartite graph with $n$ vertices in each class.) Give a proof or a counterexample.

No idea how to approach this at all and even on what the answer might be. Any help appreciated!

Comment: Are you considering induced subgraphs only?

Comment: The way the problem is phrased, it should really mean "every subgraph" and not just "every induced subgraph", but if you have an idea for both cases, feel free to mention!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is negative for $H=C_4$ and its subgraph $G$ which equals $H$ without an edge. Indeed, if a copy of $G$ is an intersection of two copies of $H$ then both copies share the same four vertices and it is easy to check that the intersection of the copies of $H$ cannot be a copy of $G$.

On the other hand, the answer is positive for each induced subgraph $G$ of $H$. Indeed, let $H’$ be a graph $H$ in which we cloned each vertex which in not in $G$. So $H’$ is a union of two copies of $H$ whose intersection is a copy of $G$. Since $H’$ is bipartite, it is a subgraph of $K_{p,p}$ for $p\le 2n_H-n_G$, where $n_H$ and $n_G$ are the numbers of vertices of graphs $H$ and $G$, respectively.